# Using the overloaded operators ">" and "<" from the vector container in the C++ STL (Not dereferencable)

Tags: c++, vector, containers, boolean-logic

This is a rather simple question, and I think it breaks down to whether or not this is legal. I have a class with the ">" and "<" operators overloaded. I'm trying to make a single statement that will return true or false without having to declare an iterator for the class, just for "simplicity".

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
class Guy
{
  double bigness; //I'm not illiterate by the way

public:
  bool operator>(const Guy& that) {return (this->bigness > that.bigness);}
};
```

Ok, this right there should work. Now I make two vectors of type guy, and I want to compare two members in a single expression so I get the truth value for that expression, like this:

```
vector<Guy> gang, mafia;
bool mafiaWins = (*(mafia.begin()) > *(gang.begin()));
```

I didn't populate the vector, so I wouldn't get anything reasonable from this code. But how could I manage to have the expression (mafia.begin() > gang.begin()) to work? I know they are both returning iterators; but dereferencing them doesn't work. Using .front() gives me the same error. I get an assertion for having a non-dereferencable iterator (Shouldn't it be dereferenciable?). I'm wondering if the problem is on not storing it in an iterator first...

Thanks for your attention

**Solution:**

So, the code I have above (Edited from when I first posted), should work for the expression. That is not the code I actually had in my .cpp, that's why its so messy. You don't need to use random access reference if you are only trying to reach the first member of the vector, and ,front() will the the reference for the first term. I originally left the vector empty in this post, because I thought it was irrelevant to populate them, and by doing that I accidentally got what my problem was in my code. The function I had getting vectors and checking their members was not checking whether or not the members I was comparing existed. So, for anyone that gets a similar assertion problem, you are possibly trying to dereference something that doesn't exist. For checking if a vector is empty there is a member function that can be used.

```
Example:
bool thereIsWar = (!(mafia.empty() && !(gang.empty()));
if(thereIsWar)
  bool mafiaWins = (*(mafia.begin()) > *(gang.being()));
```

Hope it helps anyone with a similar question

Comment: Your vectors are empty so `.begin()` on either vector won't be dereferencable. `vector` iterators are random access iterators and `<`, `>`, etc. on the iterators will work completely indepedently of whether you define these operators for your class.

Comment: I agree. I actually left the way it is my code code because when trying to dereference it didn't work. I knew the overloaded operators being used in the example above were actually from the vector not from my class, it was just so I could represent what I wanted.My problem was that I didn't realize I was actually trying to dereference something that didn't exist. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`that` is a reference.

Change:

```
bool operator>(const Guy& that) {return (this->bigness > that->bigness);}
```

To:

```
bool operator>(const Guy& that) {return (this->bigness > that.bigness);}
```

Ensure your `vector` has at least one element before testing:

```
vector<Guy> gang, mafia;

gang.push_back(Guy());  // Not sure you how you set 'bigness'.
mafia.push_back(Guy());
```

Dereference iterators for comparision:

```
bool mafiaWins = (*mafia.begin() > *gang.begin()) ;
```

Comment: We have to assume that the OP has simply made a typo when he wrote his question; it sounds like his code compiles and runs...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, ok. Missing semi-colon after class as well.

Comment: Yeap, sry about that. I actually typed the whole thing in the post. The code I was working on was too big. It was going between more than one class. I only wanted to ask how to make an expressions comparing the iterators directly since I assumed the error was there (In my code I actually dereferenced them, like I meantioned in the post). I fixed those little mistakes, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

This should work so long as the vector has contents (I get a segfault if they are empty).

```
bool mafiaWins = (*mafia.begin()) > (*gang.begin());
```

as should

```
bool mafiaWins = mafia.front() > gang.front();
```

If it doesn't fix please post the exact error.

NB: the less than/greater than operator are defined for random access iterator for comparing position.

Comment: Really? The reason why I used .front() and .begin() in the first place was because I thought that if the vector was empty it wouldn't give me an assertion error. I'll make sure I have content in it and see what happens then.

Comment: Works fine. My mistake was to dereference something that didn't exist.

Comment: Even when *A* is a valid container, *A.begin()* is *well-defined* and *perfectly valid* iterator -- it would be equal to *A.end()*.. Even if you had a STL implementation that threw exceptions when you tried to do invalid things, you would not get an exception from the *A.begin()* call. (however, dereferencing the iterator would be invalid. And comparing iterators from different containers would be invalid)